# Need to Delete CSV File in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I uploaded a .csv file to the backend of my ecommerce website. There are 30,000 products in the file, but I forgot to include the price column. I need to find this file in phpmyadmin if possible and delete it so I can upload a new one with the pricing column on it.

If I have to run a query, I will, but can someone inform me on the most efficient way to tackle this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not run a query and check for items with a *null* or zero price?  And then delete them.

Comment: Did you upload your CSV file via phpMyAdmin, or via the ecommerce application?

Comment: @MarcDelisle I uploaded via the ecommerce application. I was not sure if this would make a difference though. I'm guessing it does.

Comment: I assume that when you uploaded this CSV file, the ecommerce application used it to update its database. So, with phpMyAdmin you would not find this file, but you could access some tables of your database and fix them (provided you know how these tables work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might depend on what e-commerce solution your using but have you tried re-uploading the file with the included prices?  Typically, this will overwrite/update what you already have in the database.

Also, if you did upload a csv through an e-commerce system, it is probably stored in a writable folder on your server which you could probably get to via FTP.  However, if this csv was used to update your DB, deleting it will not have any effect on the DB itself.

This is why re-uploading the updated file will probably update your product prices on your DB as you need it to.